# Vue 3 how does reactivity work with methods

Tags: vuejs3

Hello i have array with objects and render like list. but for render `id` i call method that return `null` **on first time** init:

```
<tr v-for="i in cats" :key="i.id">
   <td>{{i.name}}</td>
   <td>{{ get(i.id) }}</td>
</tr>


<script setup>

let cats = [ { name: 'a', id: 1 }, { name: 'b', id: 2 } ]

let z = reactive({
   loadFromApi: null
})

function get(id){
   return z.loadFromApi; // first time return null
}


setTimeout(() => {
    z.loadFromApi = api.load('constant id')
}, 1000 * 5);

</script>
```

and after delay from setTimeout and load data from api i see what method 'get' call again and i see right result in html.

Question:

1. How does reactivity work with **methods**? Its **not computed** property. Its **not return "Proxy"** object for understand and trigger as "**data was changes** i should rerender \ recall method 'get'". Who is trigger method? How vue understand it?
   I always think that methods call 1 time if call from template. For rerender if data changes i shuild use computed what return WRAPPED data for template for understand that data was changes need call computed property again

Comment: Where do you invoke setTImeout?  Is it invoked in a hook? Also, You're invoking the function `get` in each iteration of the loop. That function takes an argument that you don't use. Why don't you just call {{ loadFromApi }} in template?

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero all code in <script setup>

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero  I want to understand the current situation and why it does not work according to the rules of vue

Comment: Basically, Vue is able to track the property access and mutations of a reactive object with Proxies and getter/setters. https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero I have not found an answer to my situation with methods on this link